# React: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: dispatch is not a function

Tags: react, redux

Olá,

Por algum motivo faço uma chamada e tenho o retorno desejado, porém da um erro do `Dispatch`, já testei diversas coisas e nada funciona.

**Minha action:**

```
export const formulariosExternos = dispatch => {
  return axios({
    method: "GET",
    url: `${API_CONTEUDO_EXTERNO}/conteudo/formularios-externos`,
    headers: {
      "content-type": "application/json"
    }
  }).then(response => {
    console.log("resposta do get", response.data);
    dispatch({
      type: FORMULARIOS_EXTERNOS,
      payload: response.data
    });
  });
};
```

**Reducer:**

```
case FORMULARIOS_EXTERNOS:
      console.log("reducer", action.payload)
      return {
        ...state,
        formulariosExternos: action.payload
      };
```

E **exportei no componente** assim:

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
  submitLogin,
  closeModalAvisoBloqueado, formulariosExternos
})(withRouter(LoginForm));
```

Estou **chamando em um componente** assim:

```
{console.log(this.props.formulariosExternos())}
```

Comment: Tenta com `this.props.dispatch` acho que pode ser isso

Comment: @MayconF.Castro em que momento isso?

Comment: Troca `dispatch({
      type: FORMULARIOS_EXTERNOS,
      payload: response.data
    });`

Comment: da erro do mesmo jeito, tenho outros endpoints usando esse dispatch, inclusive não acha this.props na action

Comment: Ta usando mapDispatchToProps? em connect, ao invés de usar mapStateToProps, usa null